# How to check visibility status of EditText in android?

Tags: android, android-edittext

I am changing `EditText` visibility from invisible to visible by using `setvisibility(View.INVISIBLE)` and `setvisibility(View.VISIBLE)`. But i also want to know is there any method provided in android to check `EditText`'s visibility i.e is `EditText` is visible  or any of that kind.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Here you go.. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getVisibility()

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You should be able to retrieve that by calling the method [`isShown()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#isShown%28%29) on your `EditText`.

Answer (score 19):

you can try this way also ...

```
if(edittextname.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE)
{
}
```

or

```
if(edittextname.getVisibility() == View.INVISIBLE)
{
}
```

Answer (score 15):

Try to use this method:

[isShown();](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#isShown%28%29)

Answer (score 0):

Kotlin approach -

```
val editText = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.editText)
if(editText.isVisible(){
 // do your stuff
}
```

Method -

```
fun View.isVisible() = this.visibility == View.VISIBLE  // check if view is visible

fun View.isNotVisible() = !this.isVisible() 

fun View.beVisible() = this.visibility = View.VISIBLE  // sets view visible

fun View.beGone() = this.visibility = View.GONE.       // sets view gone
```